# Data missing after upgrade from CiviCRM 4.4.14 to 4.7.13 (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

I followed the instructions of https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Wordpress#UpgradingCiviCRMforWordPress-2.BackupyourCiviCRMdatabaseandsettingsfile/s but crucially missed the line "Refer to the MySQL reference manual or the phpMyAdmin documentation if you need information on backing up your database. Note that not all versions of mysql or phpmyadmin export triggers or stored procedures by default.".

The upgrade went well and completed, but now my database is empty.  Have I lost my database?  If so, can I simply ask the website host to restore a backup to recover the last-saved data?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Did you take a back-up of your database before beginning the upgrade?

Comment: Assuming your hosting provider takes back-ups on your behalf, then the data you need is the latest version immediately prior to the point where you attempted to upgrade. Of course that data will be structured for the pre-upgrade version of CiviCRM, so you'll need to roll back your CiviCRM codebase to the pre-upgrade attempt version before you attempt to import the backed up database.